Error loading the landmark model from models/pose_model.keras: Error when deserializing class 'InputLayer' using config={'batch_shape'}
Issue Description:
I'm working on a proctoring examination system built in Python and using a MySQL database. The system includes a feature for monitoring students during exams (both objective and subjective) using TensorFlow for facial landmark detection. Recently, after upgrading libraries and attempting to match new trends and standards, I encountered an issue where the monitoring screen isn't displaying properly. I have been to successfully run the project and some of the features are working properly.
I t
Error Message:
`*WARNING:tensorflow:From E:\ExamAi\myenv\Lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

2024-07-16 19:38:07.825537: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Error loading the landmark model from models/pose_model.keras: Error when deserializing class 'InputLayer' using config={'batch_shape': [None, 4], 'dtype': 'float32', 'sparse': False, 'name': 'input_layer'}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']`

face_landmark.py:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def get_landmark_model(saved_model="models/pose_model.keras"):
    try:
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model)
        return model
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading the landmark model from {saved_model}: {e}")
        return None

def get_square_box(box):
    left_x = box[0]
    top_y = box[1]
    right_x = box[2]
    bottom_y = box[3]

    box_width = right_x - left_x
    box_height = bottom_y - top_y

    diff = box_height - box_width
    delta = int(abs(diff) / 2)

    if diff == 0:                   # Already a square.
        return box
    elif diff > 0:                  # Height > width, a slim box.
        left_x -= delta
        right_x += delta
        if diff % 2 == 1:
            right_x += 1
    else:                           # Width > height, a short box.
        top_y -= delta
        bottom_y += delta
        if diff % 2 == 1:
            bottom_y += 1

    assert ((right_x - left_x) == (bottom_y - top_y)), 'Box is not square.'

    return [left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y]

def move_box(box, offset):
    left_x = box[0] + offset[0]
    top_y = box[1] + offset[1]
    right_x = box[2] + offset[0]
    bottom_y = box[3] + offset[1]
    return [left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y]

def detect_marks(img, model, face):
    offset_y = int(abs((face[3] - face[1]) * 0.1))
    box_moved = move_box(face, [0, offset_y])
    facebox = get_square_box(box_moved)
    
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    if facebox[0] < 0:
        facebox[0] = 0
    if facebox[1] < 0:
        facebox[1] = 0
    if facebox[2] > w:
        facebox[2] = w
    if facebox[3] > h:
        facebox[3] = h
    
    face_img = img[facebox[1]: facebox[3], facebox[0]: facebox[2]]
    face_img = cv2.resize(face_img, (320, 320))
    face_img = cv2.cvtColor(face_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    predictions = model.signatures["predict"](tf.constant([face_img], dtype=tf.uint8))
    marks = np.array(predictions['output']).flatten()[:136]
    marks = np.reshape(marks, (-1, 2))
    marks *= (facebox[2] - facebox[0])
    marks[:, 0] += facebox[0]
    marks[:, 1] += facebox[1]
    marks = marks.astype(np.uint)

    return marks


saved_model.py:
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def build_model(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # 3 classes for Iris dataset
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def main():
    # Load Iris dataset
    iris = load_iris()
    X = iris.data
    y = iris.target

    # Split data into training and validation sets
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Standardize the data (mean=0, variance=1)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_val = scaler.transform(x_val)

    # Build the model
    input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],)  # Number of features
    model = build_model(input_shape)

    # Train the model
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

    # Save the model in the Keras format
    model_file = 'models/pose_model.keras'
    if not os.path.exists('models'):
        os.makedirs('models')
    if os.path.exists(model_file):
        os.remove(model_file)
    tf.keras.models.save_model(model, model_file, save_format='keras')
    print("Model saved successfully.")

    # Load the model back to check if saved correctly
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom_objects={'InputLayer': tf.keras.layers.InputLayer})
    print("Model loaded successfully.")

    # Optionally, test the loaded model
    predictions = loaded_model.predict(x_val[:5])
    print("Predictions:", predictions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Additional Notes:
I've tried creating a new pose_model.keras via the save_model.py but the issue persists.
Looking for assistance to resolve this promptly as it's crucial for a demo.
Request:
I would appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this issue, especially related to TensorFlow model loading and the InputLayer configuration. I will also be available for any online meeting.
